# Why is .subs not working in JupyterLab Python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sympy

I have a very long symbolic expression in `JupyterLab` which I am trying to substitute values in. The expression is very long so I won't elaborate on what it is unless it is necessary, but I have a simplified symbolic expression which outputs (this is using `SymPy`). I am trying to use the `.subs` command as seen below, but this is not replacing any of the variables I have and rather just outputting the same symbolic notation. I have used `.subs` before, but in a very limited capacity so I am not sure if there is a type issue or something like that. All of these variables represent those in the symbolic notation.

```
replacements=[(t1,np.pi/2), (t1d,1), (t1dd,1), (l1,1), (l2,1), (m1,1), (m2,1), (m3,1), (g,-10)]
Lagrangian = Lagrangian.subs(replacements)
display(Lagrangian)
```

These variables are defined in the following way using the `SymPy` command `symbols` and then are manipulated to get the following expression. Not all of these symbols defined are in the final expression and are intermediary symbols.

```
l1, l2= sp.symbols('l_1, l_2')
y1, y2, y3, y1d, y2d, y3d = sp.symbols('y_1, y_2, y_3, ydot_1, ydot_2, ydot_3')
t1, t2, t1d, t2d= sp.symbols('theta_1, theta_1, thetadot_1, thetadot_2')
t1dd, t2dd = sp.symbols('thetaddot_1, thetaddot_2')
m1, m2, m3 = sp.symbols('m_1, m_2, m_3')
I1, I2 = sp.symbols('I_1, I_2')
g = sp.symbols('g')
```

When it comes to `Lagrangian`, it is just a manipulatioon of alll of these variables. I will show some of the following manipulations down below, but I do not think that the are not very  necessary in causing the issue.

```
I1 = 1/3*m1*l1**2
I2 = 1/3*m2*l2**2
t2 = sp.acos(l1/l2*sp.sin(t1))
t2d = sp.diff(t2, t1) * t1d
y1 = 0.5*l1*sp.cos(t1)
y1d = sp.diff(y1,t1) * t1d
y2 = l1*sp.cos(t1) + 0.5*l2*sp.cos(t2)
y2d = 2*y1d - 0.5*l2*sp.sin(t2)*t2d
y3 = l1*sp.cos(t1) + l2*sp.cos(t2)
y3d = 2*y1d + 2*y2d
T = 0.5*m1*y1d**2 + 0.5*m2*y2d**2 + 0.5*m3*y3d**2 + 0.5*I1*t1d**2 + 0.5*I2*t2d**2
U = m1*g*y1 + m2*g*y2 + m3*g*y3

print('T=')
display(sp.simplify(T))
print('U=')
display(sp.simplify(U))


dTdTheta_dot = sp.diff(T,t1d)
dTdTheta = sp.diff(T,t1)
dUdTheta = sp.diff(U,t1)
#d_dt = 
print('dT/dtheta_dot=')
display(sp.simplify(dTdTheta_dot))
print('dT/dTheta=')
display(sp.simplify(dTdTheta))
print('dU/dTheta=')
display(sp.simplify(dUdTheta))
A = (1/3)*l1**4*l2**2*m2*t1d**2*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)**3
dA = (1/3)*l1**4*l2**4*m2*(2*t1d*t1dd*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)**3+t1d**2*sp.cos(t1)*t1d*sp.cos(t1)**3+
                           t1d**2*sp.sin(t1)*3*sp.cos(t1)**2*(-sp.sin(t1)*t1d))
B = l1**2*((1/3)*l2**2*m2*l1**2*t1d*sp.sin(t1)**3*sp.cos(t1)-(1/3)*l2**4*m2*t1d*sp.cos(t1)*sp.cos(t1))
dB = l1**2*(((1/3)*l1**2*l2**2*m2*t1dd*sp.sin(t1)**3*sp.cos(t1) - (1/3)*l1**2*l2**2*m2*t1d*3*sp.sin(t1)**2*sp.cos(t1)*t1d*sp.cos(t1) +
           (1/3)*l1**2/l2**2*m2*t1d*sp.sin(t1)**3*(-sp.sin(t1))*t1d) - ((1/3)*l1**4*m2*t1dd*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)+
                                                                       (1/3)*l2**4*m2*t1d*sp.cos(t1)*t1d*sp.cos(t1) + (1/3)*l2**4*m2*t1d*sp.sin(t1)*(-sp.sin(t1))*t1d))
C = l1**2*(l1**4*t1d*sp.sin(t1)**4 - 2*l1**2*l2**2*t1d*sp.sin(t1)**2 + l2**4*t1d)*((1/8)*m1*sp.sin(2*t1) + (3/8)*m2*sp.sin(2*t1) - (1/2)*m2)
dC = l1**2 * ((l1**4*(t1dd*sp.sin(t1)**4 + t1d*4*sp.sin(t1)**3*sp.cos(t1)*t1d) - 2*l1**2*l2**2*(t1dd*sp.sin(t1)**2 + t1d*2*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)*t1d)+l2**4*t1dd) * 
             ((1/8)*m1*sp.sin(2*t1) + (3/8)*m2*sp.sin(2*t1) - (1/2)*m2*sp.cos(2*t1)) + (l1**4*t1d*sp.sin(t1)**4 -  2*l1**2*l2**2*t1d*sp.sin(t1) + l2**4*t1d) * 
             ((1/8)*m1*sp.cos(2*t1)*2*t1d + (3/8)*m2*sp.cos(2*t1)*2*t1d - (1/2)*m2*(-sp.sin(2*t1)*2*t1d)))
D = (4*m2*sp.sin(2*t1)-3*m3*sp.cos(2*t1)) * (l1**2*sp.sin(t1)**2-l2**2)**2
dD = (4*m2*sp.cos(2*t1)*2*t1d-3*m2*(-sp.sin(2*t1))*2*t1d)*((l1**2*sp.sin(t1)**2-l2**2)**2) + (4*m2*sp.sin(2*t1)-3*m3*sp.cos(2*t1))*(2*(l1**2*sp.sin(t1)-l2**2)*(2*l1**2*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)*t1d))
E = (l1**2*sp.sin(t1)**2-l2**2)**-2
dE = -2*(l1**2*sp.sin(t1)-l2**2)**-3*(2*l1**2*sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)*t1d)
F = (dA+dB+dC+dD)*E + (A+B+C+D)*dE
display(sp.simplify(F))

Lagrangian  = F - dTdTheta + dUdTheta
display(sp.simplify(Lagrangian))
```

Does anyone know why `.subs` doesn't work? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide how you are defining `Lagrangian` and the symbols `t1, t1d, ...`?

Comment: H,i @vlovero I just updated to help explain this further.

Comment: My PC was just sitting on `Lagrangian = F - dTdTheta + dUdTheta`. So without an error message, my best advice is that your `E` and `dE` might be the ones giving you problems since you are dividing by 0 after substitution happens. So mathematically, your `F` is undefined and it doesn't fix itself with simplification. You need to find the limit of `F` wrt certain variables of your choice. All the individual limits I tried went to oo or -oo. Specifically this term `(l1**2*sp.sin(t1)-l2**2)` is causing problems.